# How to save multiple checkboxes in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, checkbox

Please i need some help in my application. 
I am using Laravel 4.2 and MySQL database. 
I am trying to use Checkboxes as some information the user have to provide to the application by checking one or more checkboxes.
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX3i7.png)

This is my view code :

```
<label for="jeux_plan"><input id="jeux" name="pieceafournir[]" value="jeux" type="checkbox" ><div ><h4>{{trans('app.jeux')}}</h4></div></label>
<label for="photocopin"><input id="photocopie" type="checkbox" name="pieceafournir[]" value="photocopie" ><div ><h4>{{trans('app.photocopie')}}</h4> </div></label>
<label for="contrat"> <input id="contrat" type="checkbox" name="pieceafournir[]" value="contrat" ><div ><h4>{{trans('app.contrat')}}</h4></div></label>
<label for="certificat"><input id="certificat" type="checkbox" name="pieceafournir[]" value="certificat" ><div ><h4>{{trans('app.certificat')}}</h4></div></label>
<label for="plan"><input id="plan" type="checkbox" name="pieceafournir[]" value="plan" ><div ><h4>{{trans('app.plan')}}</h4></div></label>
<label for="cahier"><input id="cahier" type="checkbox" name="pieceafournir[]" value="cahier" ><div ><h4>{{trans('app.cahier')}}</h4></div></label>
<label for="demande"><input id="demande" type="checkbox" name="pieceafournir[]" value="demande_autorisation" ><div ><h4>{{trans('app.demande')}}</h4></div></label>
<label for="identification"><input id="identification" type="checkbox" value="identification" name="pieceafournir[]" ><div ><h4>{{trans('app.identification')}}</h4></div></label>
```

In my model , i have one to many relationship between Project and Pieces.

```
Project(#id,project_name,project_city,...,) 
Pieces(#id,#project_id,jeux,photocopie,contrat,certificat,plan,cahier,demande,identification)
```

As you have noticied i am using boolean attribute in my Pieces table, so if the checkbox is checked it's a 1, otherwise it's a zero. 
( I dont know if it's the best way to do things or not, meanwhile i'm open to  any proposition of another efficient solution).

Now in my controller, i am getting all the information by :

```
$data = \Input::all();
$project = new Project;
$pieces = new Pieces; 

$project->project_name = $data['project_name'];
... // Other instructions
... 
save();
```

I am wondering how can i use the checkboxes and save them. 
If i am getting the checkboxes value in an array. Am i going to use a two dimensional array to save them ? I'm really blocked over here please can anyone help me ! Thanks for reading .

Comment: If you plan on saving each checkbox value separately to db, do a foreach on the `pieceafournir[]` request in your controller method, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the names how they currently are this might be an idea:

```
...
$project->save();

if (isset($data['pieceafournir'])) {
    $pieceafournir = array_fill_keys((array)$data['pieceafournir'], 1);
    $pieces->fill($pieceafournir);
}

$pieces->project_id = $project->id;
$pieces->save();
```

Makes an array keyed by those values and sets the value to 1 for each.

This only pass the fields that are checked, so the DB would have to set any field that isn't set to 0/false.

Validation and making sure the fields passed are fields the table actually has will be something to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for responding. 
If i use this solution i won't be able to know which ones are checked to associate them in the DB.
For instance, if the user checks the second, the fourth and the last one. Then i'll be having a problem, because the table wil be filled with the first tree column

Comment: you know which ones are checked ... they get inserted with value 1 the ones that are not checked aren't in the input so the db should be setup to have those fields as a default of false.